# How to change column name for multiple CSV into the same column name?

Tags: python

```
df1.rename(columns={'movie_title':'title'}, inplace=True)
```

For this it only change the specific of "movie_title". How do I code it in such a way that if it detects for example 'name' or 'titles' or 'movie_name' and change it in to 'title'?

Answer (score 0):

Add every option to the rename function:

```
df1.rename(columns={'name':'title','movie_name':'title', 'titles':'title'}, inplace=True)
```

If you want this fully automated you'll need to check for semantic similarity with `title`, eg using [this](https://pypi.org/project/semantic-text-similarity/) module:

```
from semantic_text_similarity.models import WebBertSimilarity

web_model = WebBertSimilarity(device='cpu', batch_size=10) #defaults to GPU prediction

predictions = web_model.predict([('title', i) for i in df1.columns])
scores = list(zip(df1.columns, predictions))
```

If you're certain that there is one `title` column in the df, you can rename the column name with the highest similarity score:

```
matching_col = max(scores, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
df1.rename(columns={matching_col:'title'}, inplace=True)
```

Otherwise you can set a min threshold similarity score and get the max score above that:

```
thres_val=1 #set threshold here
try:
    matching_col = max([i for i in scores if i[1]>thres_val], key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
    df1.rename(columns={matching_col:'title'}, inplace=True)
except:
    continue
```

Comment: is there a way to not add every option, and detect it automatically?

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent sure, I've added an example

Comment: When i used the semantic similarity, i had download error. How do i do to fix it ?

Comment: This could be system-dependent, start an [issue](https://github.com/AndriyMulyar/semantic-text-similarity/issues) on the repo for a solution. The code above works in google colab, so you can test it there.